# Polymorphic model in Rails / ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm a little rusty on my ActiveRecord, so forgive me if the answer is somehow obvious.

I have three model objects in a rails project: Student, Assignment, and Course. As you might imagine, a Course `has_many` assignments. Now I want to be able to assign to a Student an arbitrary number of Courses and individual Assignments.

I've tried to use a polymorphic association based on the notion of 'assignable', but can't get it to work properly.

What's the most natural way to model these relationships in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to simply say that a Student `has_many` assignments and `has_many` courses. A Course also `has_many` assignments. Of course I don't know what you're trying to achieve in your application, but it seems that courses and assignments are completely different entities, so I'm not sure why you'd like a polymorphic association.

Comment: Good point, I guess I was overthinking the problem. Course and Assignment may share certain attributes, but just because a Course is composed of Assignments doesn't mean they have polymorphic relationship.